# Problems using attribute_fu to update a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

I'm using attribute_fu and paperclip to add multiple images to a specific record.

This is working great when creating a new record but when I want to add new images to an existing record through a common scaffold update, the images upload but replace the existing images.

Any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'd found maybe the problem.

my model upload has article_id, description, photo_file_nane

In my partial: _upload.rhtml

if I just put:

```
<div class="upload">
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
<%= f.remove_link "remove" %>
</div>
```

when I update, it delete my photos.

but if I put:

```
<div class="upload">
<%= f.text_field :description %>
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
<%= f.remove_link "remove" %>
</div>
```

It works fine